# Should we remove duplicate answers on questions with many answers?

Tags: discussion

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/14378/124466), which has two similar answers, both about Foliate. https://askubuntu.com/a/1323672/124466 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1323699/124466

Is it a good idea to keep the better answer, and remove the link only answer?

This question has so many answers that it would be hard to know about other applications, if there are multiple answers about a single application.

This issue of duplicate answers are present in some other highly voted questions as well.

Comment: *"... and remove the link only answer?"* The answer you are referring to is not considered as link-only. It's a perfectly valid answer since it directly suggests a software for opening epub files, which is what the question asks for.